# Android JSON Array

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have different json arrays strings as a result of different APIs. e.g

Array no.1:

```
{
    "index0": [{
        "matchId": "55",
        "battingTeam": "Australia",
        "bowlingTeam": "England"
    }]
}
```

Array no.2:

```
{
    "onStrikePlayer": [{
        "name": "Josh Hazlewood",
        "score": "4"
    }]
}
```

So my question is, how can I get the object name (**index0**) and (**onStrikePlayer**) from above array strings in Android?
I have to compare which array I have through these `index0` and `onStrikePlayer`.

Comment: Post the code you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is JSONObject, so you should use [JSONObject.keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) to get all of the key values.

```
Iterator iterator = YOURJSONOBJECT.keys();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)iterator.next();
    if(key == YOUR_VALUE) {
        // do something
    }   
}
```

In your problem you want to get only the value of one of the keys so you should do:

```
JSONObject YOUROBJ = new JSONObject(YOURJSONSTRING);
if(YOUROBJ.has("YOURVALUE")) {
    // do something
} else if (YOUROBJ.has("ANOTHERVALUE")){
    // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonString);
if(jo.has("index0")) {
    // you have index 0
} else if (jo.has("onStrikePlayer")){
    // you have on strike player
}
```